# Theme product configurable

Tags: configurable-product

Welcome,

I used magento 1.9.0.1 My main themes is: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/... and it's cool. I can change theme my shop. But When I have product configurable, magento uses other theme. Where it is? I fight 2 days...

In the template configurable doesn't have "product-collateral" and have additional links. All is curves...

catalog.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

Where I have search?

Comment: check in catalog product design in admin catalog > manage product >edit product

Comment: In configurable and normal product is the same config :( Edit Product-> Design -> Product information column

Comment: check category custom design > Apply To Products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/colorswicher/view.phtml

Edit or Copy to your templete.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure configurable products are displayed using different theme (and if, which?), or is just the layout different?

If different theme:

- Check "catalog -> manage products -> [your product] -> design -> custom design"
- Check "catalog -> manage categories -> [your category] -> custom design -> custom design"

If just different layout:

- check "/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml": this is your template file for configurable products (if it is missing in your current template, Magento will load this file from the template your template falls back to)
- check XML for `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>`: what's inside are layout updates that only affect configurable products

Comment: I checked. Products are in the same category. Products have the same design. ..."configurable.phtml" in the template is form with configuration to product and button "add to cart". I don't see: product name, short description etc. but it is show in product. PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable is the first post